# how to set orientation for a view which is subviewed to window

Tags: objective-c

[image]

I have created a UIView.I want to subview the view to the appdelegate window

```
  UIView *newView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1048, 748)];
  AppDelegate *appdelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
  [appdelegate.window addSubview:newView];
```

This helps me to subview a view to the window.But the view is in portrait mode.I need the view to be in landscape mode .How can I set the view to the landscape mode? and I want the Red color view to completely cover the white view.how can I do so?

RedColor is the newView
white is present viewController

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if we add any object to window and then we want to change the orientation then we must use transform methods.

```
#define DegreesToRadians(degrees) (degrees *M_PI /180)
```

add above line

```
CGAffineTransform newTransform;
UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;
switch (orientation)
{
    case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
        newTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-DegreesToRadians(180));
        txt.transform = newTransform;
        txt.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
                break;
    case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
        newTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DegreesToRadians(-90));
        txt.transform = newTransform;
        txt.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);

        break;
    case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
        newTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DegreesToRadians(90));
        txt.transform = newTransform;
        txt.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);


        break;
    default: 
        newTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-DegreesToRadians(0));
        txt.transform = newTransform;
        txt.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);

        break;                             
}
```

here txt is object name,try in this way.

Comment: Thanks It works for the Orientation but I am not able to adjust the frame.

Comment: here we want to set the frame regards x and y positions,here what happened,only window is changes x,y axis are remains constant.

Comment: if you are adding view to entire window then simply change x and y values