# how to add a view or view controller on top of all other views or windows and supports orientation to that view

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

how to add a view or view controller on top of all other views or windows and supports orientation to that view. I have searched various questions, but I got the answer like adding my view on a window. But, when I add to a window, I am not able to do orientation for the view.

My class inherits from NSObject, and hence I have to add this view on a parent window of an application.

Please help. Thanks..

Comment: are you adding view to window?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12400399/how-to-set-orientation-for-a-view-which-is-subviewed-to-window/12400868#12400868

Comment: Yes.. I am adding to a window.. Thanks for the idea of Transformations..

But I m not able to adjust frame... :(